# Passing and maintaining configuration in a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a Repository in a class library that is separate from my Web API in order to maintain separation of concerns.

I want to store database configuration in my `appsettings.json` so that I can override these settings in  Azure Web Apps. This provides me a path to have separate settings for local, pre-production, and production environments.

I'm assuming the best way to provide configuration settings to the repository is to read them from the `Startup.cs` and then pass them along to the class library.

What is the best way to store these settings to ensure they persist throughout the lifecycle of the application and ensure they don't get garbage collected?

Answer (score 5):

you need to create a configuration class:

```
 public class MyLibraryConfiguration {

     public string PropertyOne {get;set;}
 }
```

and use it in your classes as a construction-time dependency:

```
 public class MyService {

      private readonly IOptions<MyLibraryConfiguration> config;
      public MyService(IOptions<MyLibraryConfiguration> config) {
          this.config = config;
      }
 }
```

than you have to register your dependencies and your config in the Startup.cs of the web project:

```
  services.Configure<MyLibraryConfiguration>(options => this.Configuration.GetSection("SectionName").Bind(options));
  services.AddScoped<MyService>();
```

then you can use MyService injecting it at construction-time

Comment: How would a separate Class Library read settings from an API configuration setting?

Comment: Class Libraries don't have settings. The project that contains the main (Web Project, Api Project, Console Project) reads the settings and than passes them to the classes of the library. The approach I suggested (called Options Pattern) gives the responsability to read the config file to the main project, while the class library uses the configurations passed.

Comment: Correct. The main focus of the question was once I have the settings stored on the API side, they need to be passed to the class library and persist there. Is a simple static class going to persist strings permanently, possibly for weeks on end?

Comment: with this solution the IOC container (ServiceCollection + ServiceProvider) is responsible to hold the reference for you. You don't have to worry about GC